# How would one go about creating Cortana as a personal assistant like in Halo?

Tags: lua, artificial-intelligence

I have been stressing myself to death trying to figure out a way to create An AI like Halos Cortana as a personal data assistant like in Halo and in the existing app.  I guess I'm wondering what I would need to know in theory in order to create an AI like her.

Comment: I doubt that such a question, as is, can be answered here. That being said, first things which come to mind would be something along the lines of Speech Recognition. You could also look into Fuzzy Logic and maybe even neural networks to help it deal and process with the information it provides and gets from you.

Comment: Thank you!  I don't think this is a very hard challenge for humans, just requires extensive knowledge and testing, but shouldn't be hard.  I used to hate ANNs but now I kind of like them.  Is there any pseudo code or code in Lua for them?  I can't seem to find source code for them.  I want to code this stuff by hand so that I gain a better understanding of it.  Thanks!

Comment: http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~cs9417ml/MLP2/ Here is a link to pseudocode for back propagation, which is a straightforward learning algorithm for feed-forward neural networks.  Maybe this will help. And yes what you described in your question is a very difficult challenge for humans.

Answer (score 1):

If you could get an answer to this question on Stack Overflow, the world would be a very different place.  Cortana would be a culmination of advanced natural language understanding and generation, knowledge representation, machine learning, planning, and goal recognition and would almost certainly be equivalent to solving the [central AI problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AI-complete).

Answer (score 0):

This question is too general to answer briefly, but if you are interested in ANN-related algorithms, then [Torch](http://torch.ch/) may be a good fit. [Awesome Machine Learning (Lua)](https://github.com/josephmisiti/awesome-machine-learning#lua) page has links to Torch packages and demos/scripts.

There is also interesting information on these and related topics in [LeCun's AMA](http://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/25lnbt/ama_yann_lecun).

Comment: Thank you.  I am not interested in any specific approach, I actually find ANN difficult to understand, but I am interested in any approach.  What approach would be best for Cortana?  I really wish Microsoft released her code.  At least snippets of it.